# Post query from php to sqlite database through button

Tags: php, html, sqlite

So I have the following webpage containing html and php. Within the page I have a checkbox which populates its options from a table within the database. and another multi-select checkbox that gets populated from a different table. The first checkbox is related to products and the second is store location which can have multiple locations.

I'm trying to setup a submit button after something is selected from both it posts to the database within the table to give store location details for each product.

table schema:

table name: products

```
id, name, StoreLocation
```

table name: stores

```
id, name
```

how I am using the product checkbox

```
  <select name="Pname">
<?php

  $resultSet = $db->query('SELECT name FROM products');
  while($row = $resultSet->fetchArray()){
    
    echo"<option value=\"productN\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
  }
?>
</select>
```

store location checkbox

```
<select name="Sname", id="Sname" multiple>
<?php
$resultSet = $db->query('SELECT name FROM stores');
  while($row = $resultSet->fetchArray()){
    
    echo"<option value=\"storeN\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
  }
?>
</select>
```

This is what I was attempting but it did not work

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="myButton" value="Submit"/>
<?php
    $query = "INSERT INTO products (Store Location) VALUES ($row)";
?>
</form>
```

Is it a problem with my setup for the sql query? When I try to use the submit button nothing is inserted to the database. I've tried sample queries and those did not work either.

Comment: Is the problem more so related with my query? I'm a beginner trying to tutorials online on how to post data but I cant find what I need.

Answer (score -1):

First: all options have the same value. You should be using the id of the record, so you can identify it, when the FORM is posted.

```
echo"<option value=\"productN\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
```

Second: This makes no sense

```
 <form action="index.php" method="post">
 <input type="submit" name="myButton" value="Submit"/>
 <?php
     $query = "INSERT INTO products (Store Location) VALUES ($row)";
 ?>
 </form>
```

If you want to react on a POST request (FORM submit) you'll receive the data of the FORM in PHP via `$_POST`. In this array, check for the name of your Submit button. For beginners it's helpful to dump the POST array, to see what it contains: `var_dump($_POST);`

Lastly: Do never pass data directly into SQL queries, use prepared statements.

Consider to make some tutorials about Webdevelopment with PHP.

Comment: so for the first problem you identified I need to show the names of the products not the ID. Would my query I used not get the entire table so the ID is accessible.

second problem, Im guessing everything I was reading took me off course because I saw you cannot directly have a button that triggers the php. So they suggested putting it within a form, within that I was testing my query.

Comment: Option has a visible part, this is used correctly. But it also needs a unique value to identify  the data. If every option has the same value, you can't distinguish them when the POST arrives. The button in the FORM triggers a new request, which is handled by PHP. This is how the web works...

Comment: ok I understand the concept of unique identifiers, I just do not know how to put it in alongside name so its not visible but searchable through it.